# Subject verb agreement with or and nor

Tags: verb-agreement

Well a silly question to ask, shall we consider ***shoes *** as singular or plural? I would say that it is plural for it has a singular form ***shoe***.

But then why do we write *Either my shoes or your coat **is** always on the floor ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the subjects joined by (Either-or), (Neither-nor) are of different persons, the verb will agree in person and number with the noun nearest to it. Also, the plural subject must be placed nearest to the verb. Ex.-Either Radha or Rani has done this mischief. Neither Mohini nor Ragini is beautiful.
Here coat is singular so only 'is'is used.